# Tomcat server is not starting with Liferay

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Liferay version 6.1 and 6.0, when I start tomcat server its not starting , window close automatically. [image]

Please provide any hints or solutions for this issue.

Comment: I think you need to be running tomcat-7.0.27

Answer (score 1):

There was problem with java version 64bit, also have to instal JRE 64bit.

**Details**
Once tomcat not started in Liferay I used Liferay IDE. Even in Eclips Juno(Liferay IDE) there was error "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:/JDK/bin/client/jvm.dll" then found solution at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk) on stackoverflow

Comment: It would be great if you could expand your answer a little, so future visitors can benefit from your solution as well. Which problem was there, exactly? Where does one get the JRE 64-bit and are there any special considerations needed while installing it?

Comment: @slhck added details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was fixed by seeing this [post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13049175).

You can try these steps:

- Go to environment variables.
- Create "CATALINA_HOME" & set the path for tomcat folder.

**Note**: You should have better `RAM` configuration.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run catalina.bat run to see what's the error. Also checkout logs for any errors. Also remove the jre_1.6.0_20 from tomcat home and install a jvm of your own. This is a 32bit jvm which doesn't handle larger heap sizes.